# GRUB is showing at boot even though it's supposed to be hidden

Tags: boot, grub2, lenovo, grub-efi

Here's my GRUB config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

My device is a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Yoga (4th gen) with 1TB NVME SSD, and running (currently) on Kubuntu 21.10.

How do I stop it from showing up and interrupting the boot process?

Comment: You've not stated where your pasted config is located; have you re-run `update-grub` to re-create the file that is used at boot? or just modified the config file that's used on next re-build.

Comment: Is the missing close quote in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="` just a typo here, or is it like that in `/etc/default/grub`?

Comment: That was my mistake.  I forgot to copy the last quote @fuzzydrawings

Comment: @guiverc I never changed anything. That's the default config.  Also ran `update-grub`, and that didn't help.  Also, I double checked `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, and it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem (on Ubuntu 21.10) and was able to fix it.

If grub finds another OS on the drive (which is true in my case because I dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows but don't need grub for that), it automatically resets the timeout to 10 if it is set to 0. You can see that when you open `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and find the following if-statement near the end of the  file:

```
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
    set timeout=10
fi
```

As `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` states itself, it is automatically generated, so if you edit the file directly, any changes to it will be lost when updating grub in the future.

To fix the issue sustainably, open `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, since this is the file the if-statement stems from. You can comment out the whole if-statement or edit it to `set timeout=0`.

Even if you're not dual-booting, look through your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to find any resets of timeout. If there are any, it should also reveal which file is inserting it. Edit that file accordingly.

Save the file, run `update-grub` and during the next boot, grub shouldn't show up anymore.

Comment: That didn't work.  Tried your solution & disable `os-prober`.  And that if statement isn't in the `grub.cfg` file (or probably not anymore).  Also, no other OS on this drive.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no clue then. Have you tried to set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to another number than 0, like 2 or 1? That way, you could test if the problem is indeed setting the timeout to 0 or if grub is not updated at all.